# Trying to copy files from current directory to another with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder on my desktop called 'Folder' and inside this folder, there is another folder called 'Internal Folder'. Inside 'Internal Folder' there is a file called 'abc.txt', and inside 'Folder', I have a batch file to copy the contents of 'Internal Folder' to another destination on the computer.

Now, I assumed that because you can run a file using `start /d "\" file.exe` ("\" being the directory that the batch file is housed) that I could use xcopy in a like fashion..

`xcopy "\Internal Folder\abc.txt" "C:\Users\Matthew"` (As an example.)

So my question is, what command can I use to copy over a file from a folder that can be moved around to different places on the hard drive, to a static directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use relative paths, this will copy the file from "Internal Folder" which resides in the current directory.

```
xcopy "Internal Folder\abc.txt" "C:\Users\Matthew"
```

In Linux the syntax is `./foldername` but in Windows the `.` is implied, which means current directory, but you can add it too as shown here:

```
xcopy ".\Internal Folder\abc.txt" "C:\Users\Matthew"
```

Answer (score 7):

if you dont want to specify the folder, you can use this;

```
 xcopy /y /s ".\*" %TEMPDIR%
```